# can we pass multiple url in a single cURL for getting products?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, curl

I want to get products from `"generic/products"` url as well as `"generic/ all_products"` url using single cURL.
here is my code,

```
<?php
  $ch = curl_init();
  $request_url = "HTTP://www.yourdomain.com/net/WebService.aspx?";
  $request_url.= "api_name=generic\all_products";

  // $request_url.="Login=xxxxx@xxx.com&EncryptedPassword=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&EDI_Name=Generic\Products&SELECT_Columns=p.ProductCode,p.ProductID,p.ProductName,p.StockStatus,pd.ProductDescription,pe.Availability,pe.CustomField1,pe.CustomField2,pe.CustomField3,pe.CustomField4,pe.CustomField5,pe.ProductPrice,pe.ProductWeight&WHERE_Column=pe.Ships_By_Itself&WHERE_Value=N";

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

  $output = curl_exec($ch);
  echo $output;
  curl_close($ch);
?>
```

in the above code ,
i want to use both request url to get products.
is there any possible to get both products using cURL??

Comment: no u can send it separately.

Comment: you can create an array for your url, and move curl request in a function and than call this function in loop

Comment: if i send separately can i use one separated call of curl in another curl

Comment: can you give me an example of calling curl request in a function and then loop it

Answer (score 0):

You can store your `URLs` in an `array` and than use it by using a loop and store result in a single `array`.

You can use like that:

```
// store url in an array.
$urlArr = array('url1','url2');
$yourProducts = array();
foreach ($urlArr as $key => $value) {
    $yourProducts[] = yourCurl($value); // call curl function. and store products in an array. you will get the all records in single arry.
}

// your CURL function
function yourCurl($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: @aravind: did you try it?

Comment: did u start use? $ch = curl_init();

Comment: function yourCurl($url){

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}

Comment: this is my function i have used                                                                  function myCurl($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
    }

Comment: the $url parameter of this function contains both 2 urls then how the curl execute that two merged url's

Comment: http://www.yourdomain.com/net/WebService.aspx?api_name=generic\all_products   is it complete url?? @aravind

Comment: i have initiated curl

Comment: no this is my url,          $request_url1 = "HTTP://www.hyperionammo.com/net/WebService.aspx?api_name=generic\all_products";

Comment: than u can also use like that: $url = "http://www.hyperionammo.com/net/WebService.aspx";
   $params = array('api_name'=>'generic\all_products');
   $query = http_build_query($params);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$url?$query");

Comment: u r welcome @aravind: if my solution solve your problem than dont forget to mark as accepted by click on the left green tick. cheers and happy new year

Comment: where is the left green tick

Comment: @aravind: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @aravind: i hope u find the way.. :)

Comment: can we avoid loop. in a single cURL request we send all the urls ?

Comment: curl will use one URL/Request at once. @MateeGojra